# Using compare algorithm in STL

Tags: c++

I am reading about algorithms at following location.

http://www.brpreiss.com/books/opus4/html/page116.html

Here it is mentioned as below

```
template <class T>
int Wrapper<T>::CompareTo (Object const& obj) const
{
    Wrapper<T> const& arg =
    dynamic_cast<Wrapper<T> const&> (obj);
    return ::Compare (datum, arg.datum);
}
```

The `CompareTo` member function is implemented in the same way as the Hash member function. I.e., it calls the global (non-member) function `::Compare` to do the actual comparison.

My question; what does author mean by global compare function in C++? Do we have to include any header file here as code is not compiling?

Comment: The only STL `compare` I know of is out of `<string>` [string::compare](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/)

Comment: It must be some sort of global function template made by the authors. That book looks pretty terrible anyway. Deriving everything from `Object`?!

Comment: My advice would be: don't worry about it. There are better ways to spend your time than trying to read the mind of the author of a book that's this thoroughly obsolete. Even assuming it was the best you could possibly hope for at the time, a book on C++ with a 1997 copyright is guaranteed to be extremely out of date.

Comment: This code has nothing to do with STL.

Comment: I guess you missed the last sentence on the page: "The implementation of a suitable compare function is left as a project for the reader"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As one of the comment mentioned above here in this context Compare is nothing to do with STL. I missed the last sentence on the page: "The implementation of a suitable compare function is left as a project for the reader"